# jQuery change ui-wrapper position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Hi all into my site I want to make an element draggable and resizable.
For some reason I want to position the element in a certain position inside the div parent.
But I can't move the ui-wrapper that contain the image cloned from another that I want to drag.
Always :

```
top:auto
left:auto
```

I have tried in this mode:

```
newDiv = $(this).clone().appendTo('#space-drawable-div').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    maxWidth: 212,
    maxHeight: 220
}).parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable({
    containment: "parent"
}).parent().removeAttr('style').css('top', '10px').css('left', '20px');
```

I have an image and its parent is 'ui-wrapper'

ui-wrapper css:

```
height: 220px;
left: auto;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
top: auto;
width: 157px;
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using jQuery's `.css()` to do this?

Comment: .css('left', '20px') I use it @Phillip

Comment: Ok... I meant for the entire process.  Can you post the HTML and some more CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the css `position` should fix the problem

```
newDiv = $(this).clone().appendTo('#space-drawable-div').resizable({
aspectRatio: true,
maxWidth: 212,
maxHeight: 220
}).parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable({
containment: "parent"
}).parent().removeAttr('style').css('top', '10px').css('left', '20px').css('position','relative');
```